# SQL Server and empty partitions scan

Tags: sql-server

Does the amount of partitions influence the cost of scan in anyway? Let's say, in case the table is daily partitioned, but most of partitions are empty, shall these be dropped of may remain in the table without any performance effect?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/268647/is-there-appreciable-overhead-from-having-a-large-proportion-of-empty-table-part/268648#268648

Comment: thank you, so much!!!!!